# Send the list (asp-items) to the session, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, selectlistitem

I´m trying to change the selection that the user sees based on the user role.
Example: if the user is admin let the selection be: admin, system ,....

I first created this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Selection { get; set; }
```

then:

```
public IActionResult Recht()
{
    if (UserModel.RECHT.Equals(50))
    {
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "SY", Text = "System" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "AD", Text = "Admin" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "ID", Text = "Innendienst" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "SP", Text = "Spediteur" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "DS", Text = "Disponent" });
      


    }
    if (UserModel.RECHT.Equals(40))
    {
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "AD", Text = "Admin" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "ID", Text = "Innendienst" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "SP", Text = "Spediteur" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "DS", Text = "Disponent" });
    }
    if (UserModel.RECHT.Equals(30))
    {
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "ID", Text = "Innendienst" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "SP", Text = "Spediteur" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "DS", Text = "Disponent" });
    }
    if (UserModel.RECHT.Equals(20))
    {

        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "SP", Text = "Spediteur" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "DS", Text = "Disponent" });
    }
    if (UserModel.RECHT.Equals(10))
    {

        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "DS", Text = "Disponent" });
        UserRoleMessage = string.Join(",", Selection);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserRoleMessage", UserRoleMessage);
    }
    

    UserRoleMessage = Convert.ToString(UserModel.RECHT);
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserRoleMessage", UserRoleMessage);


    return Page();


}
```

When I run my code I still get an empty selection.

Comment: How is the `Recht` method called? It doesn't follow the naming convention for a Razor Pages handler method: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set Selection when page load,you can call `Recht` in OnGet:

```
public void OnGet()
        {
            Recht();
        }
```

If you want to use a form to pass `UserModel.RECHT` to handler,and change the value of Selection,here is a demo:

form:

```
<form method="get" asp-page-handler="Recht">
    <input asp-for="UserModel.RECHT" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

handler:

```
[BindProperty]
public UserModel UserModel{get;set;}
public IActionResult OnGetRecht()
{
    if (UserModel.RECHT.Equals(50))
    {
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "SY", Text = "System" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "AD", Text = "Admin" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "ID", Text = "Innendienst" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "SP", Text = "Spediteur" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "DS", Text = "Disponent" });
      


    }
    if (UserModel.RECHT.Equals(40))
    {
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "AD", Text = "Admin" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "ID", Text = "Innendienst" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "SP", Text = "Spediteur" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "DS", Text = "Disponent" });
    }
    if (UserModel.RECHT.Equals(30))
    {
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "ID", Text = "Innendienst" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "SP", Text = "Spediteur" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "DS", Text = "Disponent" });
    }
    if (UserModel.RECHT.Equals(20))
    {

        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "SP", Text = "Spediteur" });
        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "DS", Text = "Disponent" });
    }
    if (UserModel.RECHT.Equals(10))
    {

        Selection.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "DS", Text = "Disponent" });
        UserRoleMessage = string.Join(",", Selection);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserRoleMessage", UserRoleMessage);
    }
    

    UserRoleMessage = Convert.ToString(UserModel.RECHT);
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserRoleMessage", UserRoleMessage);


    return Page();


}
```